# I Want A ProductDetails Class with Different Key,Value For Products Class In C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I Have This Product Class In My Project

```
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public int ProductDetailId { get; set; }

        public int BrandId { get; set; }

        public Gender GenderTypeId { get; set; }

        public int ProductCount { get; set; }

        public decimal? Price { get; set; }

        public double? Discount { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? EditDate { get; set; }


        public virtual ProductDetail ProductDetail { get; set; }
```

I Want A ProductDetails Class For Different Products
For Example:
When Customer Select TV Product ProductDetails Shows Width&Height&Inch Or When Selected A T-Shirt It Shows S-L-XL-XXL And So On...
Thanks

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: you can use dynamic class but I don't think you can save them to database if that is your intension.

Comment: "ProductDetails Shows Width&Height&Inch " What way do you want to show? Can you give an example?

Comment: You can use inheritance, You can make Abstract ProductDetails and make classes like ShirtDetails and TvDetails inherit from ProductDetails. It is a little complicated in EF core as there are multiple ways you can configure it. and you would need to cast them to their original type on the view
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritanceq) with EF core

First we define the C# class inheritance:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    //define the rest of the properties 

    public int ProductDetailId { get; set; }
    public ProductDetails ProductDetails { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ProductDetails
{
    public string ProductDetailType { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class TvDetails : ProductDetails
{
    public float Width { get; set; }
    public float Height { get; set; }
}

public class ClothDetails : ProductDetails
{
    public string Size { get; set; }
}
```

Now we need to define how to map it with EF core. there are multiple approaches as it says in the documentation I mentioned above.
By default EF core will use Table-per-hierarchy and discriminator.
you can also define the discriminator:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductDetails>()
    .HasDiscriminator(p => p.ProductDetailType );
```

Now the last problem would be we querying, we can simply cast the object based on the discriminator value.